# How to bind a key to autocompletion in nvim's terminal mode?

Tags: vim, neovim

I would like to bind CTRL-N in nvim's terminal mode to autocomplete, just like CTRL-N in insert mode.  I don't know command what CTRL-N is bound to in insert mode, so I am not sure how to bind it to the same key in another mode.  I am new to Vim and might be confused by emacs concepts here.

Answer (score 0):

The vim completion only works in insertmode, its not possible to open the completion menu in other modes.
the terminal mode however does allow you to remap keys so to make `<C-n>` activate the shells completion system one would add to init.vim

`tnoremap <C-n> <Tab>`
this might however not be what you asked for.

Comment: When I am typing shell commands in nvim's terminal, I assume I am in terminal mode.  Is that right?  Or is it insert mode?  Either way, C-n doesn't work in this mode, even though it's an insert-like mode.  Being able to do this is the main reason I want a terminal inside vim.

Answer (score 0):

your asumption is right your in terminal mode. The autocompletion feature of vim doesnt work in the terminal as its a special kind of buffer that can not be edited. There are plugins though that create a pseudo terminal where the completion menu can be used see

https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell.vim

Comment: Vimshell is a shell on its own, right?  You don't run another shell inside it?